# Change font for Edit button in navigation controller

Tags: uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

On the left side of a navigation controller I have a button I moved in through the storyboard. I have no issues configuring that one of course, but I wanted to use the Edit button you get from uncommenting out:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

But how can I customize the font name, size, and color on this button?

Here's what I tried after looking around:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 19)!]
let fontColor = [NSStrokeColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(fontColor, forState: .Normal)
```

Neither of these attributes work. Is there either:

- Another way of customizing the edit button you get from that `viewDidLoad` line (since there's no way to do it from Storyboard) or
- Is there a way to reproduce what the edit button does in code so i can customize it in Storyboard?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to customize the edit button you get from that `viewDidLoad` line. You were close, I just combined the attributes together and used `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` instead of `NSStrokeColorAttributeName`

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 19)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
self.editButtonItem().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```